# If Devise Exist Put Constraints on Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

I have a general engine I use across many apps, some require something similar to devise and require a subdomain constraints.

In main app routes.rb I tried but didn't work.

```
constraints(Devise::Constraints::SubdomainRequired) do  
    mount Example::Engine, :at => '/'
end
```

Engine routes.rb

```
    Phcmembers::Engine.routes.draw do

        if defined?(Devise) 
            constraints(Devise::Constraints::SubdomainRequired) do

                # Application Client Backend
                namespace :members do

                    # Members Main Index
                    root 'mains#index'

                    # Member Routes
                    resources :mains do 
                        resources :listings
                        resources :contacts
                    end

                end

                namespace :directory do

                    # Directory Main Index
                    root 'categories#index'

                    # Directory Routes
                    resources :categories do
                        resources :catlists
                    end
                end
            end

        else

                # Application Client Backend
                namespace :members do

                    # Members Main Index
                    root 'mains#index'

                    # Member Routes
                    resources :mains do 
                        resources :listings
                        resources :contacts
                    end

                end

                namespace :directory do

                    # Directory Main Index
                    root 'categories#index'

                    # Directory Routes
                    resources :categories do
                        resources :catlists
                    end
                end



        end

    end
```

I don't really know how to go about this hopefully somebody can give me a few pointers and clarify things. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if defined?(Devise)` is that what you're looking for?  Routes is just a ruby file, so you should be able to put it in there.

Comment: @j-dexx - Cool thanks seems to have worked. I pasted my changes above according to your comment. If you don't mind creating a short answer I can give you credit. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if defined?(Devise)
```

Is what you're looking for